# how to force the horizontal space (responsive)

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive, mobile-website

I am trying to make my website responsive, on the mobile version there is a horizontal space on the right, I would like to force it to disappear. (PS: I have no width or height on my divs)

Comment: Would you like to share any snippet so that we can refer?

Comment: Please add minimum example  :https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Thats depends on you code ..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of hiding the horizontal space would by be adding this to your `body`.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Here's a quick example:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

div {
  width: 120vw;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see everything that overflows the parent container (in that case the `body`) will be hidden.